# Could we support Launchpad as OpenID provider?

Tags: feature-request, openid

I am using Launchpad (https://launchpad.net/) as an Open Id provider and I would appreciate it, if it could be added to the open ID providers on the login-page.

In January 2009 Launchpad already had over 2.5 Million Users. Launchpad really is a huge Online-Development-Platform (driven by Canonical) and should imo be supported.

Thanks in advance

P.S.: Is this the right place to ask for something like this?

Comment: You can use Launchpad -- click More options and write your L.p. OpenID directly.

Comment: @mbq: It would still be nice to have a button there, though.

Comment: What @mbq said. Also, it already *is* supported as a top-level button on the one site where this surely makes sense: http://askubuntu.com/users/login

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann Sure; that's why I have migrated it.

Comment: @balpha: Good to know ... maybe it could be on the other sites at least in the "more OpenID options" line?

Comment: @balpha: “usually makes sense”… Aren't the OpenID choices based on usage counts? Are LJ and WP and all the others more popular than LP?

Answer (score 3):

As has already been pointed out in the comments, the [ubuntu site](https://askubuntu.com/users/login) already provides this option.
[image: ubuntu se login screenshot]

It seems a few of the sites have context sensitive login links that may be more applicable and provide a lower barrier for entry...[gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/login) for example which provides a Steam login

[image: gaming se login screenshot]

My guess is that with such a plethora of OpenID providers (And large ones to) you could have an entire screen filled with peoples choices...so they provide the 5 defaults (Stack Exchange, Google, Yahoo, myOpenID and Facebook) and then an option that is relevant to the target audience of the site...

I can't really see how this will change other than requesting LaunchPad be added to the "More OpenID Options"...